# Запятая перед или в назывном предложении

Tags: запятая

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед союзом или, если оно входит в состав поясняющего оборота? Это можно встретить во многих заглавиях. Например, "Дон Жуан, или Каменный пир".
Или, например, в таком предложении: "Перед нами Рим, или город на семи холмах". Нужна запятая или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, запятая  нужна, так как ИЛИ здесь является пояснительным союзом. Мы в этих случаях имеем два названия для одного предмета.